# Catch warnings from functions in R and still get their return-value?

Tags: r, exception, return, warnings

Within a function I'm calling another calculation-invensive foreign function, which triggers warnings in some situation, but also returns a value, which I'd like to evaluate, regardless whether warnings occurred or not.

Additionally, if warnings or errors occurred, I want to catch the warning/error messages for further processing.

The following R code demonstrates my intention:

```
hurz <- function(x) {
  # HINT: max(x) triggers a warning when x = NULL
  max(x)
  return(12345)
}

laus <- function(x) {
  r <- tryCatch({
      list(value = hurz(x), error_text = "No error.")
    }, warning = function(e) {
      error_text <- paste0("WARNING: ", e)
      # ugly hack to get the result while still catching the warning
      return(list(value = (suppressWarnings(hurz(5))), error_text = error_text))
    }, error = function(e) {
      error_text <- paste0("ERROR: ", e)
      return(list(value = NA, error_text = error_text))
    }, finally = {
    }, quiet = TRUE)
  return(r)
}
```

When errors occurr, the code ends up in the error-catch section, so it is obvious that I won't be able to get the return-value from hurz().

However, there seems to be no nice way to simultaneously get

- the return-value of hurz() as well as
- the warning produced.

When calling `laus(3)` I get the following response:

```
$value
[1] 12345

$error_text
[1] "No error."
```

On the other hand, when calling `laus(NULL)` I get:

```
[1] 12345

$error_text
[1] "WARNING: simpleWarning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf\n"
```

Of course calling hurz() wrapped with the suppressWarnings as shown above would be a really ugly hack and is no option, since hurz() performs very calculation-intensive work.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this issue in a nice way and how I can catch warnings AND still get the fuction's return-value in one go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borrowing some poorly documented R magic demonstrated in [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Resume-processing-after-warning-handler-td4357217.html), I think the following revised `laus()` function will do the trick:

```
laus <- function(x) {
  r <- 
    tryCatch(
      withCallingHandlers(
        {
          error_text <- "No error."
          list(value = hurz(x), error_text = error_text)
        }, 
        warning = function(e) {
          error_text <<- trimws(paste0("WARNING: ", e))
          invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
        }
      ), 
      error = function(e) {
        return(list(value = NA, error_text = trimws(paste0("ERROR: ", e))))
      }, 
      finally = {
      }
    )
  
  return(r)
}
```

Now I can call `laus(3)` and get:

```
$value
[1] 12345

$error_text
[1] "No error."
```

or `laus(NULL)` and get:

```
$value
[1] 12345

$error_text
[1] "WARNING: simpleWarning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"
```

or `laus(foo)` and get:

```
$value
[1] NA

$error_text
[1] "ERROR: Error in hurz(x): object 'foo' not found"
```

Note the use of `<<-` in the `warning` function.  This searches the enclosing frames of the `warning` function and overwrites the `error_text` value in the environment of the anonymous function that calls `hurz`.

I had to use a debugger with a breakpoint in the `warning` function to figure out the enclosing frames.  If you don't understand environments and frames in R, just trust that using `<<-` in this context will overwrite that `error_text` variable that is initialized to "No error."

To understand this code a bit better, realize that `withCallingHandlers()` is itself a stand-alone function.  This is illustrated by the following variation of the function, which will trap and recover from warnings, but will NOT handle errors:

```
lausOnlyHandleWarnings <- function(x) {
  r <- 
    withCallingHandlers(
      {
        error_text <- "No error."
        list(value = hurz(x), error_text = error_text)
      }, 
      warning = function(e) {
        error_text <<- trimws(paste0("WARNING: ", e))
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
      }
    )
  
  return(r)
}
```

The output from this function will be identical to the `laus()` function, unless there is an error.  In the case of an error, it will simply fail and report the error, as would any other function that lacks a `tryCatch`.  For instance, `lausOnlyHandleWarnings(foo)` yields:

```
Error in hurz(x) : object 'foo' not found
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for this solution, it works perfectly in my situation!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have implemented your solution `lausOnlyHandleWarnings`, but I'm finding that <<- doesn't modify `error_text` and I still get `No error` returned.

Comment: @Alanaj5: Can you post the code that doesn't work?  Hard to help otherwise...

Comment: @GeoffreyPoole Many thanks for your reply. The code is exactly the same as above. What I found is that `error_text <<- trimws(paste0("WARNING: ", e))` creates a new variable called `error_text`, ignoring the one returned in the list `list(value = hurz(x), error_text)`

Comment: @Alanaj5 When I copy `hurz()` from the original question, and `lausOnlyHandleWarnings()` from my answer, put them both in a script, source the script, and run `lausOnlyHandleWarnings(NULL)`, the function returns a list with `12345` as the first member, and the warning message as the second member, as expected.  This means the `warning` function is replacing `error_text` in the enclosing frame via the `<<-` operator.  So, even though you suggest your code is identical, I suspect you will need to post a working example of your code, plus your unexpected output in order to get a solution.

Comment: Sorry to dig this up, but will it make a difference, if I set `warn = 1` or `warn = 2` or will this be overridden? Made both and the output at least looks the same.

Comment: @gernophil, I’m not sure I understand what a variable called `warn` has to do with the posted question or answer. Maybe I’m missing something. What are you hoping the code will do if your sent warn=1 vs warn=2

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `warn` is a global variable, that changes the behavior of warnings (0: normal; 1: print warning immediately; 2: convert warnings to errors). The above solutions seems to override this, since `warn = 1` leads to the same output as `warn = 2`. I was just curious about this.

Comment: Ah, @gernophil.  Gotcha.  You are referring to `options("warn")`. Can't revisit the code right now, but I *beleive* that the `warning = function(e) { ... }` parameter in `withCallingHandlers()` is overriding the default warning behavior in R.  If you want this solution to be responsive to the setting for `options("warn")`, you'd want to add your own logic within the function.  Something like `warnings = function(e) { if(options("warn") == 0) { <existing logic } else { <alternative logic> } }`.  I haven't tested this to verify, however.  Others feel free to chime in here...